# Django 3: Creating a CRUD Table template (passing context variables to HTML)

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-queryset

I'm building a Crud table template as the user has many many tables to update and I'm having trouble passing on the records to the template. Here is my view:

```
def crud_table(request):
    user = request.user
    org = Organization.objects.filter(user=user)
    active_project = Project.objects.filter(organization=org[0],
                                            is_active=True)[0]
    assets = Asset.objects.filter(project=active_project)
    context_lbls = {'name': 'Name',
                    'asset_id': 'Asset ID',
                    'det_curve': "Deterioration Curve",
                    'class': 'Class',
                    'surface_type': 'Surface Type',
                    'Age': 'Age',
                    'AADT': 'AADT',
                    'AADTT': 'AADT',
                    'route': 'Bus Route',
                    'truck_route': 'Truck Route',
                    'Length': 'Asset Length',
                    'HCI': 'HCI'
                    }

    context_data = {'name': Asset.objects.filter(project=active_project),
                    'asset_id': assets.asset_id,
                    'det_curve': assets.det_curve.name,
                    'class': assets.func_class.name,
                    'surface_type': assets.surface_type.name,
                    'Age': assets.age,
                    'AADT': assets.aadt,
                    'AADTT': assets.aadtt,
                    'route': assets.is_bus_route,
                    'truck_route': assets.is_truck_route,
                    'Length': assets.length,
                    'HCI': assets.hci
                    }

    context = {'labels': context_lbls, 'records': context_data}
```

And here is my template:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                <label for="selectAll"></label>
            </span>
        </th>
        {% for l in labels %}
        <th>{{l}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                <label for="checkbox1"></label>
            </span>
        </td>
        {{ records }}
        {% for r in records %}
        <td>{{r}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My `context_data` is obviously incorrect, I'm just not sure how to pass the information to the template. I'm doing all of this to avoid having to create multiple HTML files and views. So what's the ideal way to push the data from Django to the templates?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to render template with the given context is by using `render` django shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
return render(request, 'form_template.html', context)
```

To iterate over `records` you should provide them in the format of a list, otherwise Django will iterate over keys in `records` dictionary, that is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not sure I follow 100%, do you mind expanding a bit? thanks :)

Comment: I've just meant that records should be a list than just a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Without being entirely sure what you're trying to do, it seems like you want to dump a bunch of information in a table with a checkbox by each row. I haven't tested this code, but it's probably close to what you want:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def crud_table(request):
    user = request.user
    org = Organization.objects.filter(user=user)
    active_project = Project.objects.filter(organization=org[0],
                                            is_active=True)[0]
    assets = Asset.objects.filter(project=active_project)
    context = {
        'records': [
            {
                'id': 'name',
                'label': 'Name',
                'data': Asset.objects.filter(project=active_project),
            },
            {
                'id': 'asset_id',
                'label': 'Asset ID',
                'data': assets.asset_id,
            },
            {
                'id': 'det_curve',
                'label': 'Deterioration Curve',
                'data': assets.det_curve.name,
            },
            {
                'id': 'class',
                'label': 'Class',
                'data': assets.func_class.name,
            },
            {
                'id': 'surface_type',
                'label': 'Surface Type',
                'data': assets.surface_type.name,
            },
            {
                'id': 'age',
                'label': 'Age',
                'data': assets.age,
            },
            {
                'id': 'AADT',
                'label': 'AADT',
                'data': assets.aadt,
            },
            {
                'id': 'AADTT',
                'label': 'AADTT',
                'data': assets.aadtt,
            },
            {
                'id': 'route',
                'label': 'Bus Route',
                'data': assets.is_bus_route,
            },
            {
                'id': 'truck_route',
                'label': 'Truck Route',
                'data': assets.is_truck_route,
            },
            {
                'id': 'length',
                'label': 'Length',
                'data': assets.length,
            },
            {
                'id': 'HCI',
                'label': 'HCI',
                'data': assets.hci,
            },
        ],
    }
    
    return render(request, 'form_template.html', context)
```

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                <label for="selectAll"></label>
            </span>
        </th>
        <th>
            Label
        </th>
        <th>
            Data
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for record in records %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                <label for="checkbox1"></label>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>{{ record.label }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.data }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Basically what we're doing is putting all the data into a list, where each item is a dict containing the label, data, and an id field. Then in the template, we iterate over the list of records and print a row in the table for each.

Alternatively, you could iterate over items in a dict like you have, but you'd need to be careful about order because Python dicts don't have a guaranteed ordering (at least, not until a particularly recent version of Python). To iterate over a dict's keys, you'd do something like `{% for key, record in records.items %}`.